# Pseudo random number generator with short period

Tags: random

I need to create a good quality random number generator that generates integer numbers in the range $0$ to $N-1$ where $N$ is a number in the single or tens of thousands. For example, $N=4096$.

The generator's period should be $N$ and it should output every number in its range exactly once per period. I need a good quality of "randomness". It might be useful if the generator could be shuffled (e.g. different configurations each producing a different output order).

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean for "good quality of randomnness"? "0, 1, 2, 3, ..." seems pretty random to me.

Comment: The usual statistical stuff people look for, sorry I don't know the correct terms I understand a Fourier transform of bits and whole sequence is useful in revealing any correlations / repeating aspects.